# Saving Variable in Realtime Database Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I wanna do a Calculator which can save the previous calculation into the realtime Database of Firebase. My Code below doesnt work. I dont know how to save variables into the Database

I have initialized the Database but it wont save into it

```
        buttonEqual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mValueTwo = Float.parseFloat(EditText.getText() + "");

                if (Addition == true) {
                    EditText.setText(mValueOne + mValueTwo + "");
                    Addition = false;
                    mDatabase.setValue(mValueOne +"+"+ mValueTwo);

                }

                if (mSubtract == true) {
                    EditText.setText(mValueOne - mValueTwo + "");
                    mSubtract = false;
                    mDatabase.setValue(mValueOne +"-"+ mValueTwo);

                }

                if (Multiplication == true) {
                    EditText.setText(mValueOne * mValueTwo + "");
                    Multiplication = false;
                    mDatabase.setValue(mValueOne +"*"+ mValueTwo);

                }

                if (Division == true) {
                    EditText.setText(mValueOne / mValueTwo + "");
                    Division = false;
                    mDatabase.setValue(mValueOne +"/"+ mValueTwo);

                }



            }

        });
```

Comment: `My Code below doesnt work` what does this mean ?

Comment: Have you tried to add a complete listener to a setValue() method to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.